# How do I remove a script tag by its content and its src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove a script tag (`<script>...</script>`) by its content and/or its src property. Taking as example this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var adfly_id = 2776246;
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.adf.ly/js/display.js"></script>
```

I've tried this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('script').each(function() {
        if (this.src === 'https://cdn.adf.ly/js/display.js') {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

But without success (I am using that code from within WP - if anyone is asking why that jQuery syntax), can any give me some advice?

**EDIT: The idea here is remove the script to prevent its execution**

Comment: $(this).attr('src');  should work, but keep in mind the JS has already run at that point... no reason to remove it now.

Comment: `$("script[src='https:...']").remove()` is even easier...

Comment: @jdu the idea is to prevent it for running, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery : How to find <script> elements with particular value of "type" attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984049/jquery-how-to-find-script-elements-with-particular-value-of-type-attribute), after applying a little change.

Comment: @ReynierPM you need to remove it before the page renders.  using serve side programming.

Comment: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250033/jquery-find-element-by-src-attribute#23250047) , try to use find like in the link..

Comment: That should work - if you inspect the DOM the script tag should be gone.
However, the script is probably already executed by the time your code runs.  You are better off fixing this server-side, by using [wp_dequeue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)

Comment: @Kenney that was my first thought but it's encrypted in somewhere I am not been able to find it :-\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('script').each(function() {

        if (this.src === 'URL_HERE') {

          this.parentNode.removeChild( this );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked and apparently it prevents code|script execution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the script tag I believe but I believe you can remove the src attribute in the script tag which render it useless if you removed `$(this).attr('src');`

Comment: seems like someone already suggested what I said in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('script').each(function() {
     var obj = $(this);
    if (obj.attr("src") == 'https://cdn.adf.ly/js/display.js') {
        obj.attr("src","");
     }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hack it. Use another script to do a....

```
node.parentNode.replaceChild(
  document.createComment(node.outerHTML.slice(1,-1)
    .replace(/--/g, '\\-\\-')), node);
```

Where node is your script node/element. The replacing of double dashes is to prevent the browser complaining about an uncompliant comment tag.

Then if you want to enable it just do the reverse comment.replace and enclose with < and >. But you probably need to keep track of the modified script node, because after it becomes a comment it is less query-able.

Just remember that the script is loaded early on, so your removal code should come before the node you want to remove.  I had success using and mutation observer that I start in the header that watched for added script nodes and disabled them immediately.  Then I analyzed the script node code (both as content and by

> XMLHttpRequest

-ing the `src` if it exists.  Then once I had my way with it I would re-enable it by doing the reverse disable operation by creating a code fragment and injecting the original `outerHTML`, either modified or not.